# MySQL, how can I select row based on the specific date?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following problem. Having four columns, Product_ID, Product_price, Start_date and End_date I need to select a product with the highest price on a given day(1997/12/14). The point is that product id can remain the same in few rows but the product has different prices in different time periods. I've tried to do something like this but I am getting an empty result:

```
SELECT 
Product_ID, Product_price 
FROM Products 
WHERE
Start_date >= STR_TO_DATE('1997/12/14', '%y/%m/%d')
AND 
End_date =< STR_TO_DATE('1997/12/14', '%y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: What does `STR_TO_DATE('1997/12/14', '%y/%m/%d')` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you want is more like this:

```
SELECT p.Product_ID, p.Product_price 
FROM Products p
WHERE p.Start_date <= '1997-12-14' AND 
      p.End_date >= '1997-12-14' 
ORDER BY p.Product_price DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In other words, your date comparisons are backwards.  A time period contains a particular date if it starts on or before that date and ends on or after the date.

Answer (score 0):

you could use  a join  on max price

```
  select Product_ID, Product_price 
  from Products 
  inner join (
        select max(Product_price) max_price 
        from Products
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE('1997/12/14', '%y/%m/%d') between Start_date AND   End_date 
  ) t on Products.Product_price = t.max_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this, will give you an expected result.

```
select p.ID,p.Price
from product p
where '<Your Date>'<=p.EndDate AND '<Your Date>'>=p.StartDate And p.Price=(select 
max(p.Price) from product p);
```